# How to light and shade a Poly3DCollection

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to get a 3D contour plot to shade, or have shadows so that it 'looks' 3D. I am using matplotlib, mainly due to the high quality of plots and would prefer to continue to use it.

Ultimately I would like a single or flat coloured surface with shadows cast on it in a matplotlib style plot.

I am using scipy to do some interpolation and skimage and marching cube algorithm to generate the contours. Then finally use that to create and shade the poly collection.

```py
import numpy as np
from skimage import measure
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
from matplotlib.colors import LightSource

# Generate an grid to inerpolate to
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(0.0:1.0:50j, 0.0:1.0:50j, 0.0:1.0:50j)

# Interpolate (coor and phi are the numerical grid and scalar values)
F = griddata(coor, phi, (X, Y, Z), method='nearest')

# Make the contour, marching cubes
marchCubeSpace = 1.0 / 50.0
verts, faces, normals, values = measure.marching_cubes_lewiner(F, 0.5, spacing=(marchCubeSpace, marchCubeSpace, marchCubeSpace))

# Create Ploy3D
mesh = Poly3DCollection(verts[faces], alpha=1.0)

# An attempt to get some sort of height data.
facearray = np.array([np.array((np.sum(verts[face[:], 0]/3), np.sum(verts[face[:], 1]/3), np.sum(verts[face[:], 2]/3))) for face in faces])

# light source, ultimately I want to use not `reds` but just a red for all faces.
ls = LightSource(azdeg=45.0, altdeg=90.0)
rgb = ls.blend_hsv(rgb=ls.shade(facearray, plt.cm.Reds), intensity=ls.shade_normals(normals, fraction=0.25))
mesh.set_facecolor(rgb[:, 0])

# Plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(0, 0, 0, projection='3d')
ax.add_collection3d(mesh)
```

I am looking to generate something like this:
[image]

Comment: The code isn't runnable, so one cannot find out how it currently looks like and compare to the desired image.

Comment: Yeah, you need to supply your own `coor` and `phi` values - see below I sorted it out in the end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so I have an acceptable solution. Message me if you need more help, I would be happy to walk anyone through this. Note the code below requires `coor` and `phi` from your data set, so no this code will not run if you do not provide a 3D scalar field to it.

```py
import numpy as np
from skimage import measure
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
from matplotlib.colors import LightSource

# Generate an grid to inerpolate to
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(0.0:1.0:50j, 0.0:1.0:50j, 0.0:1.0:50j)

# Interpolate (coor and phi are the numerical grid and scalar values)
F = griddata(coor, phi, (X, Y, Z), method='nearest')

# Make the contour, marching cubes
marchCubeSpace = 1.0 / 50.0
verts, faces, normals, values = measure.marching_cubes_lewiner(F, 0.5, spacing=(marchCubeSpace, marchCubeSpace, marchCubeSpace))

# Create Ploy3D and set up a light source
mesh = Poly3DCollection(verts[faces], alpha=1.0)
ls = LightSource(azdeg=225.0, altdeg=45.0)

# First change - normals are per vertex, so I made it per face.
normalsarray = np.array([np.array((np.sum(normals[face[:], 0]/3), np.sum(normals[face[:], 1]/3), np.sum(normals[face[:], 2]/3))/np.sqrt(np.sum(normals[face[:], 0]/3)**2 + np.sum(normals[face[:], 1]/3)**2 + np.sum(normals[face[:], 2]/3)**2)) for face in faces])

# Next this is more asthetic, but it prevents the shadows of the image being too dark. (linear interpolation to correct)
min = np.min(ls.shade_normals(normalsarray, fraction=1.0)) # min shade value
max = np.max(ls.shade_normals(normalsarray, fraction=1.0)) # max shade value
diff = max-min
newMin = 0.3
newMax = 0.95
newdiff = newMax-newMin

# Using a constant color, put in desired RGB values here.
colourRGB = np.array((255.0/255.0, 54.0/255.0, 57/255.0, 1.0))

# The correct shading for shadows are now applied. Use the face normals and light orientation to generate a shading value and apply to the RGB colors for each face.
rgbNew = np.array([colourRGB*(newMin + newdiff*((shade-min)/diff)) for shade in ls.shade_normals(normalsarray, fraction=1.0)])

# Apply color to face
mesh.set_facecolor(rgbNew)

# Plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(0, 0, 0, projection='3d')
ax.add_collection3d(mesh)
```

So this is what I was looking for. (Note this is not the exact same case as the above picture) [image]

Comment: This has a bug, because you are multiplying the shade by the ALPHA in the color.  It is not correct for the face normal to affect the transparency of the face.

Comment: Would it be possible to do vertex shading? i.e. interpolate over the triangle?

Answer (score 0):

New in v 3.7:  There is no need to compute the shade normals.  This is built into the [Poly3DCollection](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection.html) see parameter `lightsource`.